# 400 Bad Request when trying Ajax call to Controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I've been struggling to do a simple request from a CSHTML page to a Controller in my ASP.NET MVC website application. I'm using Ajax to try a DELETE call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/company/delete",
    type: "DELETE",
    success: function (e) {
        showAlert('Success!');
    }
});
```

And just returning a JSON on the controller side:

```
public class CompanyController : BaseController
{
    protected readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public CompanyController(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("company/delete")]
    public JsonResult DeleteCompany()
    {
        return Json("ok");
    }
}
```

`BaseController.cs`:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "IsLoggedIn")]
public class BaseController : Controller
{ }
```

Every other implementation I saw was something like this. I've tried using `@Url.Action("DeleteCompany", "Company")` as Ajax URL, removing route and requesting to `/Company/DeleteSite`, adding `[AllowAnonymous]` tag as I'm using authentication, nothing works. It will always return a *400 Bad Request* error (at least it is not *404*).

I didn't start the project, so I don't know if there is any other configurations to set and access the Controller from the View. Note that I can access my API from the Ajax and access the API from the Controller, but I'm not being successful with accessing the Controller from the View with Ajax.

Comment: Have you tried specifying `[Route("/company/delete")]`? (notice the leading slash)

Comment: @Alexander Just tried it, still receiving error 400 returns, same thing.

Comment: You may need to add verb for DELETE.  Not sure if that's there by default.  Are you sure you want to use DELETE instead of get or post?  Is company a file?

Comment: @pcalkins It is not just the DELETE method that doesn't work, I've tried with POST and GET.

Comment: Please post your controller class code as well

Comment: @Alexander Updated the question with more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was bad IIS configuration. Adding a rule to accept every type of request worked.

This is the handler in `web.config`:

```
<add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,DELETE,PUT" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your controller function return type to ActionResult instead of JsonResult

```
[HttpDelete]
[Route("company/delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteCompany()
{
    return Json("ok");
}
```

Comment: What does it change?